# Tail a file on Mainframe that needs conversion

Tags: tail, ibm-unix-system-services

I want to tail a log file in Unix system services on a Mainframe LPAR that needs a ASCII to EBCDIC conversion?

Comment: Thanks for the information; what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

```
tail /path/to/input | dd conv=ebcdic of=/dev/stdout
```

Or, to write to a file:

```
tail /path/to/input | dd conv=ebcdic of=/path/to/output
```

To convert the other way (EBCDIC to ASCII), use `conv=ascii`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `iconv`:

```
tail /path/to/file | iconv -f ISO8859-1 -t IBM-1047
```